# Network administrator in my flat - vulnerabilities?

Tags: network, wifi, peap

I'm concerned about my network that I'm currently using. There is an network on my flat with several access points in the building and the network admin is providing access - afaik it's PEAP with 802.1X

He's not the internet provider, but just normal person that manages this network.

I've got concerned when trying to connect with the Android device - it said the 'connection may not be private" without CA Certificate.

Is there any possible vulnerabilities that he could intercept any of my personal credentials i.e banking credentials etc.

Comment: If you're on a network that uses a router that he controls, he can do **everything** to your traffic. e.g.: Redirect it, MITM, SSL Stripping, ... Do NOT include his CA. `connection may not be private` is often an indication that an SSL Certificate is failing verification. Be very careful!

Comment: The need for a CA certificate for 802.1X with PEAP/TTLS/TLS seems to come up a lot and is answered many times over. Take for example my answers [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/182645/24467), [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/180794/24467) or [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/180815/24467) as just a few. The CA certificate in this case is not of concern, but that doesn't mean there couldn't be other abuses taking place.